# optimise image conversion from Ximage to rgb

Tags: c, image, jpeg, rgb, xlib

I have an ximage that I want to compress with jpeg.
But before that, I need to get the RGB values of the image.
I currently do it with the following code, which works well, but I would like to optimise it for speed.

```
void XimageToRgb(XImage* image , unsigned char* data , const int W , const int H )
{      
   unsigned long red_mask   = image->red_mask;
   unsigned long green_mask = image->green_mask;
   unsigned long blue_mask  = image->blue_mask;
   int x, y;
   int ii = 0;
   for (y = 0; y < H; y++) {
       for (x = 0; x < W; x++) {
         unsigned long pixel = XGetPixel(image,x,y);
         unsigned char blue  = (pixel & blue_mask);
         unsigned char green = (pixel & green_mask) >> 8;
         unsigned char red   = (pixel & red_mask) >> 16;
         data[ii + 2] = blue;
         data[ii + 1] = green;
         data[ii + 0] = red;
         ii += 3;
      }
   }    
}
```

Comment: What are the values of the masks? Have you compiled with `-O3 -march=native`?

Comment: the masks are : -- red : 16711680 , green : 65280  , blue : 255 -- and i am already compiling with o2 tried o3 but nothing changed

Comment: Most likely, the per-pixel call to `XGetPixel` is a major slowdown. Check if your interface allows direct access to the raw byte data. For one, you would not need those masks and shifts anymore.

Comment: Maybe you can use shared memory, as shown here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/38298349/2836621

Comment: Have you considered using `ffmpeg` to record a video of the screen and then extract just the frames that you need? What are you actually trying to do in general terms rather than just grab the screen and make a JPEG fast?

Comment: Have you considered shelling out to `xwd` (maybe in the background) to dump a given window and then convert it to a JPEG later.